# python - kivy: Display and dynamically update current time in Label widget

Tags: python, label, kivy, clock, kivy-language

I am currently developing a GUI with python and kivy. My aim is to have a Label/ Widget on a screen, which displays the current time and is updating by itself. Later I want to use that value (time) to then fill in other Input Widgets ('Use current time').

*This is the .kv file for the screen, on which I would like to have the time displayed.
For now I added a button which will trigger the function change_time in my main.py and then update the text/ Label using the label id 'current_time'. In the end this should happen automatically, without using the button*

```
<ClockScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        #Background color
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#00a7d8")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        #Input-Fields and Labels
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "right": 1}
            size_hint: 1, .8
            Label:
                id: current_time
                text: "Current Time"
            Button:
                on_press:
                    root.change_time()
            [...]
```

*This is the main.py file, where I have the function change_time in my class for the ClockScreen defined.*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import requests
import time

[...]

class ClockScreen(Screen):
    def change_time(self):
        time = time.asctime()
        current_time = self.ids.current_time
        current_time.text = time
        print(current_time.text)


[...]

GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainApp(App):
                def build(self):
                    return GUI
                def change_screen(self, screen_name):
                    screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
                    screen_manager.transition = NoTransition()
                    screen_manager.current = screen_name


MainApp().run() #Um die Mainapp zu starten
```

If I run this I get the error **"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment"**. When I define the variable time out of the class ClockScreen it works, but then the time is static and just updates once (when I run the App).

How is it possible to have the current time updated automatically and then displayed on my ClockScreen without using a button to call a function? Thanks!

Comment: When posting a traceback, please post the full thing, it almost certainly includes valuable debugging information about what lines are causing a problem.

Comment: Do not create a local variable with the same name as an imported module (like `time`). When python sees `time =` in your `change_time()` method, it creates a local variable named `time`. Then when it tries to execute `time.asctime()`, it is looking for an attribute of the newly created `time` variable. Just use a different name for the variable.

Comment: thanks a lot @JohnAnderson - changing the variable name did fix it!